# How to query all results in table and modify each row using python

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, select, while-loop

I'm trying to cycle through all rows in an **sqlite3** database table and based on the column variables enter different information into columns and rows inside another table.

I have tried loops using `fetchone()` and `fetchall()` and a simple "`while True:`" -- it all has resulted in different errors.

Below is a general example of isolated code that I think at least illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM {0}'.\
        format(ItemPrice_table))

    while True:
        row = c.fetchall()
        if(row == None):
            break

        Item = row[0]
        Price = row[1]

        if(Price <= 10):
            Category = "Low"

        if(Price > 10):
            Category = "High"

        if(Category == High):
            c.execute("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES ('{4}', 'Expensive' 'Red')".\
                format(ItemCodes_table, Code_column0, Code_column1, Code_column2, Item))

        if(Category == Low):
            c.execute("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES ('{4}', 'Cheap' 'Blue')".\
                format(ItemCodes_table, Code_column0, Code_column1, Code_column2, Item))
```

So I would expect it to cycle through each row in the "`ItemPrice_table`" and based on the price assign a category, then write this category write specific information to the "`ItemCodes_table`".

- It seems like it should be simple
- I could write a function like this in **php** easily enough
- but as I've said no matter what I do I just can't get it running

After several hours of experimentation I am all out of ideas and would really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a fetchall, you get a list  with your results. For each item of the list, you get an element is in the order your select returns. You should change your code to:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM {0}'.\
        format(ItemPrice_table))
data = c.fetchall()
for row in data:    

    Item = row[0]
    Price = row[1]

    if (Price <= 10):
        Category = "Low"

    if (Price > 10):
        Category = "High"

    if (Category == "High"):
        c.execute("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES ('{4}', 'Expensive' 'Red')". \
                  format(ItemCodes_table, Code_column0, Code_column1, Code_column2, Item))

    if (Category == "Low"):
        c.execute("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES ('{4}', 'Cheap' 'Blue')". \
                  format(ItemCodes_table, Code_column0, Code_column1, Code_column2, Item))
```

I have changed too the `Category == High` by `Category == "High"` and the same with the Low. Bu as you don ´t use the Category, you could do:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM {0}'.\
        format(ItemPrice_table))
data = c.fetchall()
for row in data:    
    Item = row[0]
    Price = row[1]

    if (Price <= 10):
        c.execute("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES ('{4}', 'Cheap' 'Blue')". \
                  format(ItemCodes_table, Code_column0, Code_column1, Code_column2, Item))

    if (Price > 10):
        c.execute("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}) VALUES ('{4}', 'Expensive' 'Red')". \
                  format(ItemCodes_table, Code_column0, Code_column1, Code_column2, Item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you could use this, with changes as you need, to do what you want all in SQL, code not needed.

Would be used easy move to another system/language.

```
INSERT INTO ItemCodes_table 
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Price <= 10 THEN 'low' ELSE 'high' END AS value_to_use,
        'whatever should be in Code_column1',
        'whatever should be in Code_column2',
        item
    FROM ItemPrice_Table
;
```

If ItemPrice_Tables data like

- 1 Itema   5
- 2 Itemb   15
- 3 Itemc   9
- 4 Itemd   11
- 5 Iteme   3
- 6 Itemf   20
- 7 Itemg   17

It gives data like

- **low**   *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Itema**
- **high**  *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Itemb**
- **low**   *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Itemc**
- **high**  *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Itemd**
- **low**   *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Iteme**
- **high**  *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Itemf**
- **high** *whatever should be in Code_column1*    *whatever should be in Code_column2*    **Itemg**

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know the kind of errors you are getting. 
But it seems `fetchall` will return a list of row tuples, your code is treating this result as a single row.

The docs (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html)  suggest treating the result of `execute` as an iterator.

So you can do:

```
for row in c.execute(...):
   ...
```

Instead of a `while True` loop.